# How to prove indicator function, step function, and then for sequences of step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

I try to proof a claim. It should be done first for indicator functions, then for step functions and finally for limits of increasing sequences of step functions. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. So I hope somebody can have a quick look at it.

This is the claim that I wanna prove:

> **Claim:** Let the function $g:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty) $ be non-increasing and $\int_{0}^{\infty} g(t)dt<\infty$. Then 
>   $$\int_{0}^{t} g(t-x)dm(x) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\mu} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x)dx \text{ as } t\rightarrow \infty.$$

i) I choose a set $A$ in $[0,\infty)$. So I set $A=[a,b]$, with $a \geq 0$ and $b< \infty$.
Therefore my function $g$ is: $$g=1_A.$$ Since the function should be non-increasing, the interval $A$ should begin at zero. So $A=[0,b]$. Is that right? If yes, then I would be finished for indicator function, since I can apply a theorem (I could add it if somebody wants). For me it would be a big release if I would know if I choosed the set $A$ right!

ii) $g$ is now a step function. So it is of the form: $$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} 1_{A_i}(x) a_i$$, where $A_i$ are intervalls of $[0,\infty)$ and $a_i$ is a non-negative real number. But since $g$ is again non-increasing, the intervalls can only be of the form $A_i=[0,b_i]$. Is this again right? If yes, then I get by using linearity of the integral and i) the right result.

iii) Now suppose $g$ is an (arbitrary) function satisfying the condition of the claim. So my increasing sequence of step functions $f_n$ is of the form:
$$f_n(x)= \begin{cases} g(x) , &x \leq n \\ 0, &x>n \end{cases}$$
So we have: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n (x) =g(x)
\text{ and } f_n (x) \leq f_{n+1}(x) \leq g(x).$$
Therefore we can add the lemma about monotone convergence:
$$\int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n (x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int f_n (x).$$
So we get:
$$\int_{0}^{t} g(t-x) dm(x) = \int_{0}^{t} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n (t-x) dm(x)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \underbrace{ \int_{0}^{t}f_n (t-x) dm(x)}_{\rightarrow \frac{1}{\mu} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n (x) dx}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{\mu} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n (x) dx = \frac{1}{\mu} \int_{0}^{\infty} \underbrace{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n (x)}_{=g(x)} dx 
= \frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) dx$$
if $t$ goes to infinity.

Is this also right?

I really hope that anybody can check if it is right or not what I did so far! I appreciate any advice, help or idea!
Thank you so far!

Comment: What are '$m$' and $\mu$ here? You are setting $A=\left[a,b\right]$ where $a\geq0$. However $a$ is allready in
use (the domain of $g$).

Comment: Yes you are right! that is my mistake! I corrected it! $m$ is a finite function and $\mu=\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$, where $X$ is an non-negative random variable.

Comment: For $g=1_{\left[0,b\right]}$ and $t\geq b$ I come to $\int_{0}^{t}g(t-x)dm(x)=\int_{t-b}^{t}dm(x)=m(t)-m(t-b)$. Does that agree with your observation? And also: is there a relation between function $m$ and rv $X$?

Comment: yes I have the same. But my question is more if I choosed my $g$ right? Do you know that? And yess there is a relation!

Comment: If $g$ is non-increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and is an indicatorfunction
of set $A$ then you have $x\in A\wedge y<x\Rightarrow y\in A$. This
leaves the following possibilities for $A$: $[0,b]$ or $[0,b)$ for $b\geq0$, and $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you!! It helped me a lot!! It is the same as I thougth, but maybe I didn't write it so well!! I also added part iii) of the proof! Maybe you can help me there as well!! I appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clarify what $\mu$, $m$ are (in your comment you are nor really precise, I guess $X$ is not just some random Variable, but is related to the integral you're computing). Since your question is not really about that, I will answer the other parts.

First, you need to understand that you are not "choosing" $A$. $A \subset (0,\infty)$ should be an arbitrary set, such that $1_A$ is non-increasing. This means that $1_A(x) \geq 1_A(y)$ whenever $0 \leq x \leq y$. In other words $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $y \in A$ implies $x \in A$, which means $A$ is of the form $[0,a]$ or $[0,a)$ for some $a \geq 0$.

For the second part, the argumentation should be similarly. By the same argument the support of $g$ will be of the form $[0,a]$ or $[0,a)$. Assume that the $a_i$ are sorted increasingly. Then take $B_1:=[0,a]$ (or $[0,a)$) and $b_1=a_1$. Then consider $g-a_1 \cdot 1_{B_1}$ and do the same to get $B_2=[0,a']$ (or $[0,a')$) and take $b_2=a_2-a_1$. Going on like that you receive $B_i$ and $b_i$, such that $g=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i 1_{B_i}$. But now the functions $1_{B_i}$ are suitable to apply (i).

For (iii) your idea is good, but the functions $f_n$ aren't step functions in general. It is not too hard to find such functions though. There's a well known way to find a monotone sequence of simple functions $f_n$ converging pointwise to $g$ whenever $g$ is measurable by separating the y axis (you probably did this in class). You just need to verify why these functions are non-increasing step functions in your case.

Comment: thank you so far! I didn't add the informations about $\mu, m, X,..$ because it would be just to much... I edited my question. I added part iii). Maybe you can have also a look at it!

Comment: I added a comment on part (iii).

Comment: I have a question to ii). So for $x\leq y$, it is again $g(x)\geq g(y)$. This is the same as:$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 1_{A_i}(x) a_i \geq \sum_{i=0}^{n} 1_{A_i}(x) a_i.$ This implies again for $y \in A_i$, that $x \in A_i$. So again $A_i$ is of the form $[0, b_i]$ or$[0,b_i)$ for some $b_i \geq 0$. But as if you said, that the $A_i$ are disjoint, then all $A_i$ have to be equal or isn't it?? Otherwise they can't be of the form $[0, b_i]$ or$[0,b_i)$... hmmm...

Comment: Actually you're right. I am fixing it.

Comment: Okay, basically you can take $A_i$ all to be Intervals starting at $0$ without changing $g$. I edited my post and described how to do this.

Comment: Thank you. But then we need the condition $a \geq a' \geq a''...$ or isn't it? Because we get: $g=\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_i 1_{B_i}=a_1 (1_{B_1}(x)-1_{B_2}(x)-...-1_{B_n}(x))+a_2 (1_{B_2}(x)-1_{B_3}(x)-...-1_{B_n}(x))+...+a_n 1_{B_n}(x)=a_1 (1_{B_1}(x)-(1_{B_2}(x)+...+1_{B_n}(x)))+a_2 (1_{B_2}(x)-(1_{B_3}(x)+...+1_{B_n}(x)))+...+a_n 1_{B_n}(x)=a_1 (1_{B_1}(x)-1_{B_2 \cup ... \cup B_n}(x))+a_2 (1_{B_2}(x)-1_{B_3 \cup ... \cup B_n}(x))+...+a_n 1_{B_n}(x)$

Comment: That follows from the construction and $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$

Comment: Hmm if I'm honest I don't really get it. I have that $g=\sum 1_{A_i} a_i$. Since $g$ has to be non-increasing, I get that all $A_i$ are of the form $[0,a]$ or $[0,a)$. This is clear. But why I have to do that what you did? I mean then we get $g=\sum 1_{B_i} b_i$ and so the $B_i$ are also of the form $[0,a]$ or $[0,a)$. What is the difference or the advantage? Sorry but I really don't see it...

Comment: In general you can't say that all $A_i$ are of that form. Take $1_{[0,1]}+0.5 \cdot 1_{[1,2]}$ for example. What I did is showing that there is a representation of the very same function such that all $A_i$ are of the desired form. It sounds more complicated than it is. Try to draw a picture!

Comment: thank you so much! I understand it now!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Define $f_{n}:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by $x\mapsto n^{-1}\lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor$.
Then it is a non-increasing stepfunction converging to $g$ with $f_n(x)\leq g(x)$ for every $x$ and every $n$.

Non-increasing because $g$ is non-increasing.

A stepfunction because its image is finite.

The convergence is not necessarily monotonic, but because $0\leq f_n\leq g$
and $\int gd\lambda<\infty$ you can use the [Lebesguetheorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to prove
that $\int f_{n}d\lambda\rightarrow\int gd\lambda$.

**addendum**:

$g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is non-increasing and consequenty
the image of $ng$ is a subset of $\left[0,nc\right]$ where $c:=g\left(0\right)$.

Then the image of $\lfloor ng\rfloor$ is the a subset of the nonnegative
integers that do not exceed $nc$. That is a finite set and it follows
directly that the image of $f_{n}=n^{-1}\lfloor ng\rfloor$ is a finite set.

We have: $$\lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor\leq ng\left(x\right)<\lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor+1$$
hence: $$n^{-1}\lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor\leq g\left(x\right)<n^{-1}\lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor+n^{-1}$$
This statement is equivalent with: $$0\leq g\left(x\right)-f_{n}\left(x\right)<n^{-1}$$
Then evidently:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! But why follows from finite image that $f_n$ is a stepfunction? That is not obvious for me...

Comment: If function $f$ takes values $\left\{ a_{1},\dots,a_{n}\right\} $
then it can be written as $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}1_{A_{i}}$ where
$A_{i}=\left\{ x\mid f\left(x\right)=a_{i}\right\} $. Isn't that
a step function in your view?

Comment: yess you are right!! that's now clear to me!! thank you very much! 2 last question; how can I proof $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{n} \lfloor ng\left(x\right)\rfloor= g(x)$? Intuitive it is clear, but a proof would be great! An the other question is maybe silly, but why is the image of $f_n$ finite?

Comment: I have edited now.

Comment: thank you very much!! YOu helped me a lot!!

Comment: You are very welcome.